# cookie header is present in request but saved in browser in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

i am making a cors request to node express from react fetch for auth. i recieved cookie header in response but it does not saved in browser but when i make another request it browser will send the previous cookie which was recieved in previous request.

Note , This happens only in production .everything fine in developement mode. I google it and try different method adding credential : 'include', sameSite none ,secure , httpOnly and even domain but it does not worked.

Here is my backend code

```
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
                    res.cookie('token', token,{
                        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 864000000), // for 10 days in production only 864000000
                        sameSite: 'none',
                        secure:true
                     }
                     )
                }else{
                    res.cookie('token', token, {
                        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 864000000), // for 10 days in production only 864000000
                        sameSite: 'none',
                    })
                }
```

here is my frontend code to signin

```
const result = await fetch(`${import.meta.env.DEV ? import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_DEV_URL : import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_URL}/v3/api/user/signin`, {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials:'include',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email,
                password
            })
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Cookies set in one environment will be present in the other, as long as the name is the same.

You could change the names, like appending "-dev" for every cookie when not in production:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    res.cookie('token', token, {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 864000000), // for 10 days in production only 864000000
        sameSite: 'none'
    })
} else {
    res.cookie('token-dev', token, { //changed here
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 864000000), // for 10 days in production only 864000000
        sameSite: 'none'
    })
}
```

Comment: As you suggest , change the cookie name i changed it but it does not saved the cookie in browser . this happens only in production.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove 'secure' property. I edited it now. Maybe, the difference is because of it.

Comment: it does not work. the problem i recieved ,sent cookie in production but cookie doesn't store in the browser. this happen only in production . In localhost cors every thing fine.